# Log4j2 log4j-core

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have added spring-boot-starter-log4j2 dependency in pom.xml which is of version 2.2.5. I am trying to change the version of org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-core from 2.12.1 to 2.13.3
However, in doing so I am getting runtime exception. I went through other solutions which suggest that maybe log4j jar is included twice. I am unable to solve the error by excluding that also. This runtime exception occurs only when org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-core version is changed. Changing version of other api included under spring-boot-starter-log4j2 does not cause any exception.
What am I missing?
Pom.xml
...

```
  <!-- Add Log4j2 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>
```

...
Dependency Tree
[Dependency Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrOCt.png)
Runtime Exception
...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.getStringProperty([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/util/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.BasicAuthorizationProvider.<init>(BasicAuthorizationProvider.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.authorizationProvider(ConfigurationFactory.java:216)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getInstance(ConfigurationFactory.java:189)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:687)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:708)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:243)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:648)
at com.vzw.jitrjis.StartUp.<clinit>(StartUp.java:22)
```

...

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions, don't. You are probably overriding parts of the Spring Boot supplied dependencies instead of using the preferred way of overriding versions (by just specifying the version).

Comment: If this is a maven project. You can find out the conflicting jars using the dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

You have two version of log4j jars in the classpath. This is causing the classpath conflicts. Log4j might be included in the classpath with transitive dependencies. 
If you want to identify the multiple jars, try viewing the dependency tree.
If you are using maven , it is as simple as running this command.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: No, I already mentioned I tried this method but not working for me. I am using eclipse so I can see dependency tree directly there.

Comment: You "can't try that in Eclipse". It's not accurate; you need to run your commands first on the CLI. Unless you provide more details, or some other dependency is bringing also Log4J `2.x`, this should solve your issue.

Comment: The error you are getting is par of log4j-api dependency. Look for this dependency in the dependency tree . It would be included multiple times in the classpath. If you find it use maven exclusion to exclude that.

Comment: I was facing the same error, i decided to keep log4j1.x and remove all log4j2.x dependencies. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the version of Log4j2 do not add the dependency on spring-boot-starter-logging-Log4j2. Just add Log4J-bom with import scope to the dependencyManagement to control the version and then add the various Log4J dependencies you want. Spring will have no problem using a newer version of Log4j2.